# Query about Ramond-Ramond fluxes associated with a Dp-brane

Tags: string-theory, branes

A paragraph in the string theory book by Ibanez and Uranga ([String Theory and Particle Physics by Luis Ibáñez and Angel Uranga](https://books.google.com/books?id=vAUUu6DpVkUC&lpg=PP1&dq=string%20theory%20and%20particle%20physics&pg=PA156#v=onepage&q&f=false)) has confused me.

According to the book (for a screenshot of the paragraph and figure, please click [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=vAUUu6DpVkUC&lpg=PP1&dq=string%20theory%20and%20particle%20physics&pg=PA156#v=onepage&q&f=false) to visit a Google Books excerpt), the closed string sector in the presence of a Dp-brane describes the fluctuations of the theory around the vacuum, while the open string sector describes the fluctuations of the Dp-brane itself. And that the closed string sector is responsibile for the emission of gravitons and components of the RR $(p+1)$-form along the brane volume. So far so good.

But then, it is stated that for $p < 9$, it is perfectly alright to consider configurations of D-branes without orientifold planes because for $p < 9$, the flux-lines of the RR field can escape to infinity, and there are no RR tadpole cancellation constraints. This seems too general an observation, and seems to simply suggest that orientifold planes can be discarded. But I am sure I misunderstand what the authors are saying here.

Could someone clear this up?